# MySQL Event run after one hour, but with zero mins and sec

Tags: mysql

How to start MySQL Event run after one hour of install? But I want with zero mins and seconds. Example if current time is `17:06:58` run Event at `18:00:00`.

```
CREATE EVENT my_event
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 DAY
        STARTS NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR ??????
DO
    # My query
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give the starttime and the schedule direct.

```
CREATE EVENT test_event 
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 hour 
   STARTS DATE_FORMAT(
             date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) , "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00"
          )
   DO 
   UPDATE test.t1 SET a = a + 1;
```

SELECT DATE_FORMAT( date_add(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) , "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00" );

Comment: Bernd, I need auto date that can be run anytime, but don't know it is possible

Comment: so, you mean when you start at 20:05 so it must start at 21:00. I have change my Answer.

Comment: I got it worked, thanks!

CREATE EVENT test_event 
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 hour 
   STARTS DATE_FORMAT(
             DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR , "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00")
          )
   DO 
   UPDATE test.t1 SET a = a + 1;